# Private static inner class - Powermock

Tags: java, mocking, powermock

I want to mock private static inner class using Powermock (based on EasyMock). This does not come from production code, it's just a question whether something is possible. I am pretty sure this is bad design, but it's something I'm trying for science.

Let's say we have a class with static private inner class:

```
public class Final {
    private static class Inner {
        private final int method () { return 5; }
    }

    public int callInnerClassMethod () {
        return new Inner().method();
    }
}
```

I would like to mock the `Inner` class and its `method`.

I have come out with the code as follows:

```
    Class<?> innerType = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(Final.class, "Inner");
    Object innerTypeMock = PowerMock.createMock(innerType);
    PowerMock.expectNew(innerType).andReturn(innerType);
    PowerMock.expectPrivate(innerType, "method").andReturn(42);
    PowerMock.replay(innerTypeMock);
    new Final().callInnerClassMethod();
```

In the code: we get the type of `Inner.class` and mock it, when a user creates new object of type `Inner` we say that we return our instance, and when someone calls its `method` we provide our implementation for it.

Generally, I am learning about mocking and one can be sure this code proves I don't know what I'm doing. The code does not even compile and I get the following error on the line `PowerMock.expectNew(innerType).andReturn(innerType)`:

> andReturn (capture) in IExpectationSetters cannot be applied to
>   (java.lang.Object)

Is the mocking of private static inner class even possible? I have not found a definitive code example on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get around the compile error by using bare `Class innerType = ...` instead of `Class<?> innerType = ...` in my code. It feels wrong, but works. I'd grateful if someone explained the difference and how to make it work in the original example. There were also some places where I mixed `innerType` and `innerTypeMock`. The full, working test code looks as follows:

```
Class innerType = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(Final.class, "Inner");
Object innerTypeMock = PowerMock.createMock(innerType);
PowerMock.expectNew(innerType).andReturn(innerTypeMock);
PowerMock.expectPrivate(innerTypeMock, "method").andReturn(42);
PowerMock.replayAll();
System.out.println(""+new Final().callInnerClassMethod());
```